# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connection'

Tags: python, sqlite, attributeerror

The beginning of my code is:

```
import sqlite3

def construct_query(card_name, card_type,card_type_whole, power, tough, card_text, exp,rare):

    query = "INSERT INTO CardComponet (all column names) VALUES ('{}','{}',{},{},'{}','{}','{}')".format(card_name, card_type_whole, power, tough, card_text, exp,rare)
    return query

path_to_flat_file = 'C:\Users\Mrs Rose\Desktop\inputf.txt'

flat_file_object  = open(path_to_flat_file, 'r')

connection = sqlite3.connection('practice1.db')

cursor  = connection.cursor()
```

But my error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mrs rose\Desktop\FinalProject.py", line 11, in <module>
    connection = sqlite3.connection('practice1.db')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connection'
```

I tried changing my .py name and my my database name but nothing is working. Please help if you can.

Comment: I think you meant: `connection = sqlite3.connect('practice1.db')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sqlite3.connection` does not exist.  The function you are looking for is called [`sqlite3.connect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect):

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.connect
<built-in function connect>
>>>
```

Also, you should never use `str.format` or similar tools to insert values into a query.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html):

> Usually your SQL operations will need to use values from Python
>   variables. You shouldn’t assemble your query using Python’s string
>   operations because doing so is insecure; it makes your program
>   vulnerable to an SQL injection attack (see http://xkcd.com/327/ for
>   humorous example of what can go wrong).
>
> Instead, use the DB-API's parameter substitution. Put `?` as a
>   placeholder wherever you want to use a value, and then provide a tuple
>   of values as the second argument to the cursor's `execute()` method.
>   (Other database modules may use a different placeholder, such as `%s` or
>   `:1`.)

Comment: thank you soo much! I am not familiar with python at all

Comment: So i actually tried the ? and I got this error --> OperationalError: attempt to write a readonly database

Comment: That is not a problem with `?`.  Your database is readonly.  Meaning, you cannot edit its contents but only read them.

Comment: how do I change this setting?

Comment: I'm not an expert in databases, but that setting is usually based on your user permissions.  If you are not the owner of the database, then you will need to have the owner change the permissions for you.  If you are the owner, then you can do this yourself.  Basically, when the database was created, it was marked as readonly.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3 module does not have attribute named "connection" it does however have an attribute named connect. You should try 'connection = sqlite3.connect('practice1.db')'

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of possible mistakes:

1. From the file path, I guess that you are on window. Well, you need to change the file path: `C:\\Users\\Mrs Rose\\Desktop\\` to avoid to be confused as an escaped character.
2. On my IDE, the `sqlite3` module does not have the method `connection`.. maybe `connect`?